# Conditionally show image in a repeater if the database is not null

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I have a repeater that includes as image. However, there is an image that may not be in all of the Promotions in this repeater

```
<div class="promo">
    <h2><%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Title %></h2>
    <p><img src="/Uploads/<%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Image %>" alt="" class="promoImg" /><%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Description %></p>
    <p><em><%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Restrictions %></em></p>
</div>
```

Can someone show me how to make the  only show up if that entry does not have a null field?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer do something in server side, so, my sugestion is:

Add a event handler to your repeater

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="myRpt" runat="server" onitemdatabound="myRpt_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="promo">
            <h2>
                <%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Title %></h2>
            <p>
                <asp:Image ID="imgTest" CssClass="promoImg" ImageUrl="" runat="server" />
                <%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Description %></p>
            <p>
                <em>
                    <%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Restrictions %>
                </em>
            </p>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

i will "bind" the image source in code behind, you could do it for other controls too.
So, the code behind is:

```
protected void myRpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType ==     ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Image imgTest = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgTest");
            Promotion pActual = (Promotion)e.Item.DataItem;
            bool needToShowImage = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(pActual.Image)

            if (needToShowImage)
            {                    
                imgTest.ImageUrl = "Uploads/" + pActual.Image;
            }
            else
            {
                imgTest.Visible = false;
            }                
        }
    }
```

It will do the trick. If it dont work, please, let me know.

Comment: where is needToShowImage defined?

Comment: You wrote: "there is an image that may not be in all of the Promotions", so, tell me you? Whats the rule for the image that dont need to be shown.

Comment: if the field does not nave a filename in the column the image doesn't need to show up.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

For C#.Net:

```
<div class="promo">
    <h2><%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Title %></h2>
    <p><img runat="server" visible='<%# Information.IsDBNull(((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Image) %>' src=""/Uploads/<%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Image.ToString %>" alt="no image found" class="promoImg" /><%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Description %></p>
    <p><em><%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Restrictions %></em></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I should clarify the Image column only stores the string filename.  It seems with this solution that only the src attribute would change.  I'd like to remove the img tag all together

Comment: Are you using VB.Net or C#.Net?

Comment: C# - I simply added some jquery to the page: to check each image and if the attr src is null then I hide the image.  I'm open to a server side solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some jquery to check each image on the page to make sure there is a image associated with that promotion:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.promoImg').each(function (index) {

    if ($(this).attr('src') == "/Uploads/") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

});

I'm still interested in a server side solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use panel to do this.

```
  <div class="promo">
<h2><%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Title %></h2>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlImage" runat="server">

<p><img src="/Uploads/<%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Image %>" alt="" class="promoImg" /><%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Description %></p>

</asp:Panel>

<p><em><%# ((Promotion)Container.DataItem).Restrictions %></em></p>
```

In ItemDataBound event, do this

```
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
 if (((Promotion)e.Item.DataItem).Image == null) {
    ((Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlImage")).Visible = false;
 }
```

when panel is invisible, it will not be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

why not use the

```
<% if()%>
```

to judge either there is a image source? if not ,then didn't response.so we can save more